# Change size of higher hierarchy div when playing youtube in iframe

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, focus

I can change the height of a div with the :focus class. So:

```
<div id="ytb"></div>
```

...is changed with a click on the div with the :focus pseudo class css:

```
#ytb {
width:75px;
height:50px;
}
#ytb:focus {
height 100px;
}
```

But when I nest a youtube video via iframe in the #ytb div, a click on the div just wouldn't change the height anymore. I think the focus goes to a div inside the iframe. also tried the :focus-within class. But it didn't work. How can I get this to run?

Comment: Under what circumstances does your example code work? Can you provide some more context?

Comment: If you click on div id="ytb", it changes height. Is that enough context? Wouldn't know what else to tell...